# Access to Samba Server From another network

Tags: networking, server, samba

I have Samba File transfer for my office. It works very well but I need connect to server from home or another location How can I do this?

Comment: Hello. wich os version is on the server? what os are you running on the client? Your best option to do that will be to install openvpn in that server.

Comment: Hello, Server running with ubuntu 18.04 and samba version4, Clients are Windows10. How can I configure that can you help me please I dont know  where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar running.

1. Intall OpenVPN on the server Here is a guide.[(Install Open VPN 18.04)](https://tecadmin.net/install-openvpn-server-ubuntu/)
2. Instal OpenVPN client on the PC/Client[(open vpn client for windows)](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/)
3. You will need to open the VPN port usually 1194 on the server and network (virutal port/NAT maybe).
4. once you setup your connection you will be able to access you files in two steps.

> a) connect to the vpn
> b) access the server through the windows explorer using the IP.

Good Luck.

Comment: Last question how about security can I trust to openVPN

Comment: Yes. Open VPN uses certs and authorization. I have been using it for years. Nonetheless, if your server it is going to be public you need to have other security measures as well. Firewall, Secured configuration on sshd (no root access) at least. I can even acces my home files from an Android phone with my confguration.